# How to replace part of a String that was created with gson.tojson? Android

Tags: android, json, gson

I have this code:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(selectedEquipment);
```

so JSON is like this:

```
[
{"datetime":"Nov 20, 201514:45:00",
"latitude":0.0,
"longitude":0.0,
"model":"ENG",
"name":"null",
"serialNumber":"011",
"urgency":"HIGH_URGENCY",
"version":"null"}
]
```

I want to remove `"urgency":"HIGH_URGENCY"` or replace `"HIGH_URGENCY"` for "1".

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove urgency property from your input element:

```
selectedEquipment[0].remove("urgency");
```

or modify its value:

```
selectedEquipment[0].addProperty("urgency","1");
```

or replace "HIGH_URGENCY" in the output string:

```
json = json.replace("HIGH_URGENCY", "1");
```

I'd go with the first or second solution since it handles the json object before its conversion.

Answer (score 0):

when you use that function "toJson" you will get a String, so you can simply do this

```
// To replace with 1
String json = new Gson().toJson(selectedEquipment);
json = json.replace("\"HIGH_URGENCY\"", "1");
```

or

```
// To remove
String json = new Gson().toJson(selectedEquipment);
json = json.replace("\"urgency\":\"HIGH_URGENCY\",", " ");
```